# Use more than one physical interface on devstack ocata

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-neutron

I have a barebones PC with 6 physical interfaces to 'play' around with devstack. I'd like to deploy VMs on it and connect them to different Ethernet interfaces. Currently, I'm only able to use the interface associated to the br-ex bridge. I've tried to define several OVS bridges and assign the physical interfaces to different bridges. I try to define a mapping with more than one bridge, but that doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone had any success on this.

Thanks, /PA

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create "provider networks", which allow you to associate neutron networks with specific physical interfaces.  You can find documentation on creating provider networks in [the install guide](https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/install-guide-ubuntu/launch-instance-networks-provider.html).

Once everything is configured correctly, you can attach new Nova servers to your provider networks by passing the appropriate `--network` argument when you boot a new server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see the guide is OpenStack generic and I'll try it out. I was looking for something more devstack specific though. Something to put in my ~stack/devstack/local.conf file and avoid having to do too much magic when I bring up the devtsack node.